# Use selected item from Spinner in conditional Operation (if statement)

Tags: android, spinner, onitemclick

Please, I have two `spinners`. I am trying to get `string` values from `spinnerA` and then, to use these values as condition for display other values from `spinnerB`. I get these values from the database (mySql). 
A part of the code is below. The syntax is correct (Android Studio doesn't show any error), but nothing happen when I run it on the emulator I mean, the `Toast` doesn't show.

Any idea of the issue OR of the simplest way to do that please ?

PS : the `Toast` here is just to check if the value is stored.

```
public class ReviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner sp1, sp2;
TextView companyName;
Toolbar toolbar;

ArrayList<String> trajets = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> horaires = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1, adapter2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);

    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_trajet);
    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_horaire);

    adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.travel_spinner_layout,R.id.txt,trajets);
    sp1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
               String travel = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
               if (travel == "NY - CA") {
                    Toast.makeText(ReviewActivity.this, "Yaounde - Douala", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (travel == "CA - NY") {
                    Toast.makeText(ReviewActivity.this, "Douala - Yaounde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

    });
```

Comment: You can't compare string using == use .equals() method !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, this change your `==` to `equals()` in

**`itemSelectedListener`**

see the changes below -:

```
String travel = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
           if (travel.equals("NY - CA")) {
                Toast.makeText(ReviewActivity.this, "Yaounde - Douala", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (travel.equals("CA - NY")) {
                Toast.makeText(ReviewActivity.this, "Douala - Yaounde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

The “**`==`**” operator is used to compare 2 objects, it checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in memory. In other words, it checks to see if the 2 object names are basically references to the same memory location.

**and**

The **`equals()`** method to compare 2 `String` objects, then as long as the actual sequence of `characters` is equal, both objects are considered `equal`

[**Here**](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/) you can read what is difference between **`==`** and **`equals()`** in java.

Comment: Works perfect ! Thank you so much for your answer and the explanation, makes sense.

Comment: glad it works please accept this answer if helps @user3805411

Answer (score 0):

`==` is bad for comparing Strings (any objects really, unless you know they're canonical).  `==` just compares object references.  `.equals()` tests for equality. For Strings, often they'll be the same but not guaranteed always.

> The `==` operator checks if the two strings are exactly the same object.
>
> The `.equals()` method  check if the two strings have the same value.

Comment: It works, thank you !!